# WCF Scope defaults to tempuri despite being explicitly and programmatically added to service

Tags: .net, wcf, scope

On the service end I have a service host spinning up in the context of a Windows service. Everything seems to go fine: the service spins up and can be discovered. But when I go to check the scope at the client that I explicitly added in the service (no matter what the value) I get the following value: {urn:http://tempuri.org/:MyServiceInterface}

The service side discovery code looks like this:

```
var udpDiscoveryEndpoint = new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint();
//
// Create a scope unique to this machine for filtering purposes and add it to the discovery behavior
//
var endpointDiscoveryBehavoir = new EndpointDiscoveryBehavior();
endpointDiscoveryBehavoir.Scopes.Add( new Uri( address + "/disco" ) );
udpDiscoveryEndpoint.Behaviors.Add( endpointDiscoveryBehavoir );
//
// Add discovery endpoint
//
_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint( udpDiscoveryEndpoint );
ServiceDiscoveryBehavior serviceDiscoveryBehavior = new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior();
_serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add( serviceDiscoveryBehavior );
```

Comment: I was adding the EndPointDiscoveryBehavoir to the UdpDiscoveryEndpoint instead of the service endpoint.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it either. It has something to do with either running it as a windows service or calling the discovery client from the test environment... ugh.

Comment: what about modifying the service contract namespace?

Answer (score 1):

As I guessed, you might add a metadata endpoint to your service as well? If it's the case, you should add the scope behavior to your **metadata endpoint as well**, so that you can discover the service with the right scope.

Cheers.